# Wordpress dashboard half blank screen

Tags: wordpress, screen, dashboard

Wordpress dashboard blank screen like below

[Explaning Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1NsT.png)

i tried to 
off debug 
rename plugins and themes 
edit screen.php codes
repair DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code Increase PHP Memory Limit

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
```

Please check below things also.

- Problems in your web host.
- Remove empty lines and PHP closing tag (?>) from wp-config file.